Name of this futuristic movie about cloning?
I think it was made between the 80s and 90s. It was about two doctors, friends, that were developing cloning when a man appears and shoots one of them. The doctor wakes up only to discover he is in the future, that the cloning has been finished and used and that his friend, an old man now, controls everything. His old friend even has an army and every time some officer dies he clones them so that they can keep working.
Lots of things happen and it turns out that the doctor is not the original one, that his old friend has woken him up lots of times as a clone and now pretends to transfer his memories into his body. The doctor and a revolutionary woman that he liked foil the plan and as the old man had everything prepared to make the doctor "his heir" he becomes the owner of everything.
Does anyone remember the name of this movie please?

Sounds like Johnny 2.0 from 1997 with Jeff Fahey, John Neville and Michael Ironside.

Awakening from a 15-year coma, scientist Johnny Dalton (Fahey) discovers that his life has been illusory and that he is merely a clone of the real Dr. Dalton. With the help of rebel leader Nikki Holland (Welch), Dalton sets out to find his maker in a futuristic society fraught with danger and secrecy.

The clone was implanted with the memories of the original scientist in order to find a certain program. Here's the trailer:




Yes!! That's the one! Thank you!!
